# Recursive digit sum hackerrank javascript runtime error on 3 tests

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, math, data-structures

I am trying to solve `Recurive Digit Sum`, and I actually solved it, but I got `3 runtime errors` on `large inputs` when submitting.
I have optimized my code a lot, but still I am getting `runtime errors`. I have **googled** and tried every answers/solutions I got on Internet, but they were all wrong, those codes were not able to pass all tests cases. I think my code should be optimized more, but I don't know how.
**Here is my code:**

```
function superDigit(n, k) {
    // Write your code here
    if (n < 10) return n
    
    let c = ""
    let i = 0
    if (k && k > 0) {
        while(i < k) {
            c += n
            i++
        }
    }
    
    return findSum(c === "" ? n : c)
}

function findSum(n) {    
    let sum = 0
    let i = 0
    while(i < n.length) {
        sum += +n[i]
        i++
    }
    
    if (sum < 10) return sum
    
    return findSum(sum.toString())
}
```

**I am stuck, any help would be appreciated!**

Comment: Could you also publish your test cases?

Comment: @CarstenMassmann I just optimized more, and all tests cases are passed now.

Answer (score 1):

I just optimized my code more, and all test cases are passed.
**Note:** I am not using any built-in method like `reduce`, otherwise this code should have been shorter with `reduce`

```
function superDigit(n, k) {
    // Write your code here
    
    if (n.length === 1) return n
    
    const nArr = n.split('')
    let sum = 0
    let i = 0
    while(i < nArr.length) {
        sum += +nArr[i]
        i++
    }
    sum = (sum * k) + ''
    
    return superDigit(sum, 1)
}
```

Comment: First thing first - for external source, please include the link or complete description to make it easier to understand and help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that your approach works. Below you will also find my take on it: `digsum()`:

```js
function digsum(n){
  return n<10? n :
   digsum((""+n).split("").reduce((a,c)=>+a+(+c)))
}

function superDigit(n, k) {
// Write your code here
if (n < 10) return n

let c = ""
let i = 0
if (k && k > 0) {
    while(i < k) {
        c += n
        i++
    }
}

return findSum(c === "" ? n : c)
}

function findSum(n) {    
let sum = 0
let i = 0
while(i < n.length) {
    sum += +n[i]
    i++
}

if (sum < 10) return sum

return findSum(sum.toString())
}

[123456,6600,888885439].forEach(n=>
 console.log(superDigit(n,1),digsum(n)));
```

Comment: Actually, I am not using any built-in methods to solve any problem like `reduce`

Comment: Good to know. These challenges often are a little contrived. But I am glad you could fix and confirm your solution! 